# WIF how to create a claim for my server side? Does I need to create a STS?

Tags: wif

What I purposed to do is, I want to do is I want to create a Claim based Authentication.
But I use a public Auth provider such as LIVE connect API.
So it only return OAuth based data to me.

Considered I'm the server side, I just want to

1 get the data with OAuth.
2 convert it to claim.
3 set current principal to the claim I created.

Do I need to create a STS?
And can I use these this claim achieve SSO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And have a look [here](http://thinktecture.github.com/) where he actually implements it.

Or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446535.aspx) which shows how to do it with Azure ACS.

Comment: Thanks very much! I found the solution in your first link, With ADFS you can create custom claims transformation modules.

Answer (score 1):

You create Security Token Service (STS) when you want to decouple your authentication logic from your business logic in a way that it works as two separate services / applications, where one is issuing Security Tokens, and the other one (or more of them) are consuming them.

To me it seems that you should implement your own ClaimsAuthenticationManager that will convert all the data received by OAuth (which is doing authentication for you) to claims, generate ClaimsPrincipal with it and add your own business logic claims to it as well => set generated principal to be your current principal.

Depending on what libraries are you using for OAuth, some of them will create initial claims principal for you, which you can then take in ClaimsAuthenticationManager, and convert it to your own claims principal.

For more reference on it, check www.leastprivillege.com, Dominick has nice series of articles about OAuth and claims based authentication.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's what I looking for!I will read the resource you provide, thanks.